# The easiest way to find an orientation of parametrized surface

Tags: integration

I am trying to understand how can I find proper orientation of my surface. There are two options:inside and outside(what in cases when we have a plane ? )
So there is an example that I have problem with:
Given surface(orientated to the top):
$$x=u+v$$
$$y=u-v$$
$$z=u$$
on the area $$(u,v)=[0,1] [0,1]$$
over a vector field $$F=[x^2,y^2,z^2]$$
So i can easily find out normal vector, but what about the orientation of that vector.How can I state whether my  vector is pointing out correct direction given ?Any help appreciated !